# Accessing chromium classes on Android

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, chromium

I am trying to get a grip of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474086/accesibility-talkback-and-webview) by debugging over Android classes myself. I have seen that in the accessibility TTL process there's a `AccessibilityInjector` class involved, that's stored in the `com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility` 
package.

The problem is, I cannot access these clases and when browsing throught the android.jar library I cannot even find this package structure. Is there any way that I can debug over these Chromium classes?

Answer (score 0):

`AccessibilityInjector` is class in Chromium and it's not including in `android.jar`
(https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/accessibility/AccessibilityInjector.java)

I think if you want to debug it, you have to rebuild the chromium webview:
http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-android-webview

Comment: Yet I can access the WebView class which is part of Android. How do those two "connect"?